# nested divs wont show both background colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the css

```
.Shell {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:25px;
  background:green;
    }

.Inner {
  width:50px;
  background:red;
    }
</style>
```

And here is the html

```
<body>
<div class="Shell">
<div class="Inner" id="Inner"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

I have researched some things on google but most of those were syntax related or too different from my html to apply.

In IE9 and firefox the red color for the Inner div does not show.  Shouldn't the Inner div override the background color of the Shell div?

Comment: try adding padding/spacing to the inner shell to see which overrides which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.Inner` does not have a height set, and you should also put a non-breaking space inside:

```
 <div class="Inner" id="Inner">&nbsp;</div>
```